# Convert an Android Project to a Java Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project

Is it possible to change an Android Project to a Java Project, without losing git history of files ?

Thanks

Note: The current Android project doesn't contain any Android API code and doesn't import any Android package.

Comment: Just fork it and make the changes. Or you could branch it if you wanted to keep it in the same repo.

Comment: If the file locations/names etc. don't change why should you lose history info? Note that there are certainly a couple of files that have to be replaced because of the different ui and runtime.

Comment: Isn't an Android project a subset of Java projects?

Comment: @EmbattledSwag Yes ! What property in .project file should I edit or remove so the project will be considered as a Java Project ?

Comment: Being somewhat pragmatically minded, I might be tempted to make a copy of the tree, delete the project, create a new empty java project, copy the files you want to keep over and then do a git diff and see if the changes indicated seem appropriately confined.  Fix anything that doesn't seem right, git add the new project-defining files and commit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close your project and Modify two files

**.project**

- Delete any `<buildCommand>...<buildCommand/>` Android related
- Delete `<nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>`

**.classpath**

- Delete any `<classpathentry .. />` Android related
- Add `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>`

Finally clean your project from any folder or other things Android related and reopen your project and you should notice that the project is converted to a Java Project

Answer (score 1):

An android project is a Java project. If you are saying that you want to create a copy that you can run locally (essential run the back end)

Create a branch/fork of your current project, delete all the android related code, add a main method that will run the project.

If you are trying to port an android project to a desktop application that is a different issue.